# How to interleave different types in ByteBuffer for OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, bytebuffer

I'm drawing some objects with OpenGL ES 2.0, and each vertex has several attributes which, as recommended for best performance, I'm storing interleaved in a single buffer. Some of these (like position) are represented with floats (`GLES20.GL_FLOAT`), but I'm passing in a color, and it's wasteful of memory to pass the color attribute as four float components so I'd like to use `GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. Four of these will pack into one 32 bit field. However I can't figure out an easy way of storing these in `ByteBuffer`s. E.g. using `GL_FLOAT` for the colours I'd do the following:

```
    void addVertex(float xpos, float ypos, int color) {
        floatBuffer.put(xpos);
        floatBuffer.put(ypos);
        floatBuffer.put(Color.red(color) / 255f);
        floatBuffer.put(Color.green(color) / 255f);
        floatBuffer.put(Color.blue(color) / 255f);
        floatBuffer.put(Color.alpha(color) / 255f);
    }
```

This works, but I'm using 128 bits to represent a colour that could be represented in 32, which will also cause a performance hit. So what I'd like to do is create a `ByteBuffer` and use `asFloatBuffer()` to create an alias to it and use whichever is appropriate for the type being stored. Like so:

```
    void addVertices() {
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexCount * VERTEX_STRIDE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        floatBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        for(Vertex v : vertices)
            addVertex(v.x, v.y, v.color);
    }

    void addVertex(float xpos, float ypos, int color) {
        floatBuffer.put(xpos);
        floatBuffer.put(ypos);
        byteBuffer.put(Color.red(color));
        byteBuffer.put(Color.green(color));
        byteBuffer.put(Color.blue(color));
        byteBuffer.put(Color.alpha(color));        }
```

However this won't work because `asFloatBuffer()` creates a `FloatBuffer` that shares the underlying storage of the `ByteBuffer`, but maintains its own position index. I'd have to manually track the position and update each one before storing anything, which is ugly.

I could also split the attributes into separate buffers, but the performance penalty for that would probably outweigh the gain.

Any ideas on how to do this in an elegant, efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ByteBuffer` has additional methods that can be used to put other data types besides `byte` into the buffer, in a machine-independent way. So instead of wrapping the `ByteBuffer` in a `FloatBuffer`, use the `ByteBuffer` directly, and use `putFloat()` to append the `float` values:

```
void addVertex(float xpos, float ypos, int color) {
    byteBuffer.putFloat(xpos);
    byteBuffer.putFloat(ypos);
    byteBuffer.put((byte)Color.red(color));
    byteBuffer.put((byte)Color.green(color));
    byteBuffer.put((byte)Color.blue(color));
    byteBuffer.put((byte)Color.alpha(color));     
}
```

Comment: The order of a created `bytebuffer` [is big endian](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order()). As GLES is a native library, you should make sure the byte order is set to the native byte order, by setting `buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())` before putting any float values in the buffer.

Comment: If you bothered to read my original question, you would have seen that I was indeed setting native byte order.

Answer (score -1):

You could either pack the color into one float and put that into the float buffer, or split the position into bytes and put them into the byte buffer.

As an example, here's how to do the former:

Assuming 0-255 `int`s, first pack them into one `int`:

```
int colorBits = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;
```

then make that into a `float`:

```
float floatColor = Float.intBitsToFloat(colorBits);
floatBuffer.put(floatColor);
```

Comment: That makes an assumption about the endianness of a float. So it is efficient, but hardly elegant, and likely to break on different hardware.

Comment: The solution turns out to be ridiculously simple. See my answer.

Comment: No, that's incorrect: a `floatbuffer` that is created by allocation or wrapping a float array has [the native byte order of the underlying system](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#order()). As GLES is a native library, it should be in the native byte order.